# How to display PID<100 processes by using ps and grep?

Tags: unix, grep, pid

Is there a way use ps -ef|grep command to display the processes Within a certain range, say less 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ ps -ef | awk '$2<100'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well.